# Auto bundle assets process, wordpress theme-plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, webpack, bundle, assets

I'm looking for advice to manage the bundle assets process of a wordpress theme, suited to my theme workflow structure.

I ve a lot of COMPONENT, for every COMPONENT there is a dedicated folder, inside that there is a .php file that own a PHP Class, an "assets" folder with css and js file for that component:

```
|-- /wp-content/themes/MY-EXMPLE-THEME/xxx/xxx/ALL-COMPONENT
    |-- MY-EXAMPLE-COMPONENT
    |   |-- my-example-component-class.php
    |   |-- templates
    |       |-- my-example-component-template-part.php
    |   |-- assets
    |       |-- my-example-component-style.css
    |       |-- my-example-component-script.js
    |
    |-- MY-EXAMPLE-COMPONENT-2
    |   |-- my-example-component-2-class.php
    |   |-- templates
    |       |-- my-example-component-2-template-part.php
    |   |-- assets
    |       |-- my-example-component-2-style.css
    |       |-- my-example-component-2-script.js
    |
     ...
```

my-example-component-class.php

```
Class MY_EXAMPLE_COMPONENT {

    public static function init() {
      self::initialize_assets();
    }

    public static function initialize_assets() {
      wp_enqueue_style( ".../assets/my-example-component-style.css", ...);
      wp_enqueue_script(".../assets/my-example-component-script.js", ...)
    }

    public static function render() {
      get_template_part(".../templates/my-example-component-template-part");
    }

}

add_action( ‘init’, [ ‘MY_EXAMPLE_COMPONENT’, ‘init’]);
```

So when i want to render it i simply call

```
<?php MY_EXAMPLE_COMPONENT::render(); ?>
```

Said so, i ve a large amount of HTTP Requests.
I'd like to reduce that amount by bundling assets into only two files:

```
bundle.css
bundle.js
```

I’ve never used but i know that there is Webpack for a task like this.

For what i know , a usual way of utilize Webpack is to put all the assets in a “src” named folder, then run Webpack and it will create the bundled files to a “dist” folder..

In my case this means copyng all the assets from every COMPONENT folder to that "src" folder, manually.

This is a problem, because when i want for example create a new version of the MY-EXAMPLE-COMPONENT, i need to manually check the "src" (for Webpack) folder and , if necessary, delete the old version assets , and adding the new version assets, then bundle again..

The Way i created my Workflow is to help my mind , by having every COMPONENT isolated by the other, assets included.

Said so , my goals are:

```
1. Maintain my workflow folder structure.
2. Have a way of auto bundle all the component assets togheter without manually cloning these files to the “src” ( for Webpack ) folder.
```

Possible solutions that i thought , to achive my goal are:

```
1_ Create a script ( in PHP or in NODE ) that , creates an empty “src” folder, then search for assets in components folders and auto copy all the matches to the src folder, then i manually run webpack.

2_ Do the same process ( empty “src” folder -> cloning there all assets ) via Webpack.
```

Any suggestions ?

PS:
Just in case , i ve a version of MY-THEME in Wordpress standard way of doing things, so a folder with all the template part in a “template” folder ( all mixed together )., an “assets” folder with css and js files (all mixed toghtere) , but id like to try to not adopt that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future readers:

#### I've created the script suited for my project.

It get all css and js files from folders that i defined, divide them in group, merge all the group togheter, process js with babel and uglifyjs, process css with uglifycss, and copy the results files back to WP theme.

https://github.com/tresorama/wt_theme_node_auto_bundle

You can clone and edit to make it works with your folder structure.

### How it works?

Clone the repo as SUBFOLDER of your WP theme, edit what need to be edited ( details below), enter to that folder with terminal, and run

```
npm install
npm run production
```

### What you need to edit ?

some const defined inside "create-bundle.js".

### In which way ?

"create-bundle.js" is a a file that make two things:

1. CLONE => copy all css and js file from different sources defined in a const CLONE = {....} and paste them into a "src" folder.
   **YOU must adapt const CLONE**
2. BUNDLE - Step 1 => Using rules defined by const PREBUNDLE_... , create some minibundle of files , and put these minibundle inside "pre_bundle" folder, with the purpose of concat files with same priority ( especially for css files , in order to maintain the cascade ).
   **YOU must adapt const PREBUNDLE_...**
3. BUNDLE - Step 2 => get these minibundle files, concat again and put in "preprocess" fodler, in order specified by "const FINALBUNDLE_..."
   **YOU must adapt const FINALBUNDLE_...**